# Bootstrap 3.0.0: How to use data-slide-to outside of indicators?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to make a small gallery like the one shown below -
[image]

I'm sure you've all seen them considering they are fairly common. When trying to make one using bootstrap I ran into a major problem. I can't seem to link the smaller bottom images to the larger top one that was when one of the smaller ones is clicked it changes to the selected image. I am attempting to use data-slide-to however it does not seem to work outside of the "carousel-indicators". I can't put it into the carousel indicators list because that moves the images up into the gallery (It may be possible to fix this with CSS but my attempts have been worthless). Does anyone know the problem? I've tried  tags around each image that didn't seem to work then I tried divs. Still nothing.

Things I've tried:

- encasing images in .
- Moving the smaller images in and out of carousel inner.
- Making a custom class for the smaller images.

Things to note:

- I am using 3.0.0
- All images are generated (if you haven't guessed already)
- Smaller images are separate from larger one (not auto scaled down)

Things I plan on trying:

- data-target
- changing id
- Changing class of div tag that encapsulates everything.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your issue with your code?  You can use http://www.bootply.com/ to build an example.

Comment: @Trevor Sorry I didn't get around to that. After a few more attempts (I did the things I said I was going to try) I ended up fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out bootstrap requires you to id the carousel as "myCarousel" and then use data-targets for each image. After changing the ID and setting the data target the gallery now works.

Comment: This helped me, thanks!. Just for clarification: any id for the carousel will work, as long as you point to the same id in data-target attribute (data-target="#myid")